# Delete cookie containing string in Splinter using Python

Tags: python, selenium, cookies, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I'm using Splinter with PhantonJS and I need to delete a cookie that contains a given string.

For example I have a cookie that have in the name "hello" but I don't know the full cookie name.

I've thought about the following code but this doesn't seem to work!

```
    for cookie in driver.get_cookies():
        if "hello" in cookie:
            print "Cookie deleted";
            driver.delete_cookie(cookie)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for cookie in driver.get_cookies():
    if "hello" in cookie:
    print "Cookie deleted"
    cookie = cookie.replace('hello', '')
```

strings are immutable in python so str.replace() will return a copy of str. to "delete" the substring from the str, you'll have to assign str to the copy created by replace

Comment: Trying to run the code printing the cookies before and after the deletion and it's not working, it's not deleting the cookie at all